# How do I change gcc compiler versions when using Visual Studio / CMake / WSL

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am setting up to cross-compile an application developed for Windows (Visual Studio 2019, MSbuild) to a linux target.

I have installed WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 (which "comes packaged with" gcc/g++ version **9**) and am also in the process of setting up CMake to do the linux build out of the same project directory as Windows builds from.

Everything was going well until I realized that I needed gcc/g++ version **10** in order to have some newer c++20 features (one of which is the new "numbers" library for purposes of this question).

So I installed gcc/g++ version 10 on the Ubuntu WSL VM and I can see that the /usr/include/c++/10 directory is now populated with the new "numbers" header (yay!) and the v10 compiler is also called via the CMake build with no errors (yay!).

However, Visual Studio *IntelliSense* reports that the new header is missing, and so it appears to need a "push" to explicitly update the copied/synchronized c++ standard library headers from /usr/include/c++/10 on Ubuntu to the appropriate Windows directory, which is something like: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\wsl_ubuntu2004\usr\include\c++\

Currently, IntelliSense only has access to the prior version's /usr/include/c++/**9** headers in that Windows directory.

Question:  What do I do in order to force Visual Studio to start synchronizing the headers in that v10 directory so IntelliSense can parse them?  I am not super familiar with the way CMake works, nor am I very familiar with the .json configuration files which Visual Studio uses when it interacts with my project configurations and CMake.

Or do I need to copy them manually from the Ubuntu VM to Windows?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a **Rescan Solution** in Visual Studio (from the Project menu) caused a background task to update the HeaderCache in the appropriate Windows folder from the corresponding /usr/include/ folder on the WSL remote, over the course of several minutes.

Although this didn't immediately cause Intellisense to recognize the availability of the newly-copied headers right away, after several restarts of Visual Studio, toggling back-and-forth between a "x64-debug" (Windows) and the "WSL-GCC-Debug" (Linux) configuration, and trashing the CMakeCache.txt (and other CMake build artifacts) following with a fresh building the CMakeLists file, Intellisense *finally* started parsing the new folder and recognized the new header.